# simplest way to show function is bijective

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Verify that $f(x) = \frac{2x-1}{2x(1-x)}$ is bijective on (0,1).

to show the function is injective.

$f(x)=f(y) \rightarrow x=y$

$\frac{2x-1}{2x(1-x)}=\frac{2y-1}{2y(1-y)}$

$(2x-1)2y(1-y)=(2y-1)2x(1-x)$

$4xy-4xy^2-2y+2y^2=4xy-4x^2y-2x+2x^2$

$-2xy^2-y+y^2=2x^2y-x+x^2$

At this point it's clear that x=y, but factoring it all out and arriving there algebraically is unreasonable. Is there a better way to show it, or a property that allows me to conclude it at this step.

for surjectivity $\forall b \in B \exists a \in A (f(a)=b)$

then $\frac{2a-1}{2a(1-a)}=b$

This needs to be solved for a, to show that for all b, there exist an a. During the last equation into a polynomial we get

$2ba^2+a(2-2b)-1=0$ this gives the following two answers

$a= \frac{(2b-2) \pm\sqrt{(2-2b)^2-4(2b)(-1)}}{2(2b)}$ which holds whenever $b \neq 0$

does this answer need to be expressed in any other, simpler way? I assume not since there's no variable, other than b?

Comment: You need to show that your $a$ is in $(0,1)$.

Comment: It is not possible to determine if $f$ is surjective or not without knowing the codomain; for example $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $x\mapsto x^2$ is not surjective, but $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_+$, $x\mapsto x^2$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $f$ on the interval $(0,1)$ is
$$
  f'(x) = \frac{(x-1/2)^2 + 1/4}{x^2(1-x)^2}.
$$
Clearly, $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x\in (0,1)$, so the function $f$ is strictly increasing. This implies that the function $f$ is injective on the interval $(0,1)$, and even that it is bijective from $(0,1)$ to its image. As $f$ is continuous on the interval $(0,1)$, the intermediate value theorem say its image is an interval. Given that $f$ is increasing, it is the interval $(\lim_{0^+} f, \lim_{1^-} f)$. We have $\lim_{x\to 0} 2x - 1 = -1$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} 2x(1-x) = 0$ with $2x(1-x) > 0$ on $(0,1)$, so $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = -\infty$.
In the same way, we find that $\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x) = +\infty$.

We have proved that $f$ is a bijection from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Outline of proof**:

You have to show: $0<\dfrac{2b-2+\sqrt{4b^2+4}}{4b} < 1$, and this is clear, and also $(x-y)(2xy+1-x-y) = 0$. If $x = y$ then you're done, if not $2xy+1-x-y=0 \Rightarrow y = \dfrac{x-1}{2x-1}$. You have to show that $\dfrac{x-1}{2x-1} \notin (0,1)$ whenever $x \in (0,1)$.